# Using NSPredicate to Sort Core Data in a Table View (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I am new to Core Data in Swift and need help using NSPredicate. I currently have a table view and a search bar in my app. I also have an entity called Item with an attribute of allergen (string). I want to filter this table view so that cells only display if searchBar.text is equal to Item.allergen.

```
func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)

    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]
    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]
    } else {
        if searchBar.text != nil, searchBar.text != ""{
            print("Search bar text exists")
            print(searchBar.text!)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]

            //Search; Only display cell if searchBar.text = Item.allergen


        } else {
            print("Search bar text does not exist!")
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]
        }
    }

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self

    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

I attempted to use NSPredicate to do this, but it resulted in a key path not found in entity error. I would include this code, but I'm sure it was entirely wrong.

Any advice?

**Update:**

[Here's a picture of the Item entity's attributes in the Core Data Model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjzPi.png)[This is the code in the ItemEntity.swift file, I think this was autogenerated?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUUS.png) Hopefully this is what you needed.

**Update 2:**
Thanks for the help! I found a solution. This is the code that worked for me:

```
let userSearch = searchBar.text!
commitPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "allergen == %@", userSearch)
fetchRequest.predicate = commitPredicate
```

Comment: Can you also post your Item class here? Want to see properties of the class.

Comment: Not related but why do you create always new fetched results controllers? Add a property `sortDescriptors` and use the `didSet` observer to update the `sortDescriptors` of the predicate of the controller and perform a fetch.

Comment: Do you want to sort objects when the segmented controller is selected?

Comment: The sorting objects part works fine. If segment 3 (the search segment) is selected, and text is entered in the search bar (searchBar.text), I want to filter the core data so only cells with the allergen attribute equal to searchBar.text are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following predicate to filter only those which exactly match your search text:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"allergen == %@", searchBar.text)
```

Alternatively, you might want to match if the `allergen` string contains the search text:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"allergen CONTAINS %@", searchBar.text)
```

To make the comparison case and diacritic insensitive, add `[cd]` (so `... ==[cd] ...` or `... CONTAINS[cd] ...`).